# What should we do about these two duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

I just came across this question:

- [What determines whether a magic item requires attunement?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87689/52137)

which reminded me of a question I answered:

- [How can I decide if my homebrew item should require attunement?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/153370/52137)

which  appears to clearly be duplicates. I believe newer questions should normally be closed as duplicates of older ones, ideally before answers come in. However, that did not happen this time and the newer question has more upvotes and the answer to the new as more upvotes than either of the older ones and is (in my probably biased opinion) better.

Should the older be closed as a dupe of the newer? And/or should they be merged, and if so which way?

Comment: As record-keeping: As of time of writing, the latter question has been marked as a duplicate of the older one.

Comment: Related: [Should an old duplicate of an even older question be newly marked as such?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7787/should-an-old-duplicate-of-an-even-older-question-be-newly-marked-as-such), [What do we do when there are duplicate questions that get missed?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/what-do-we-do-when-there-are-duplicate-questions-that-get-missed), [Duplicate question with better documented answers](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6202/duplicate-question-with-better-documented-answers)

Answer (score 9):

### The 'better' question should not be closed

'Better', of course, being a bit subjective but including which question most clearly spells out the problem, which has attracted the 'better' answer(s) etc. Older is better than newer if everything else is equal(ish).